# AirConsole Game develoment - Control with Sprites?

Tags: android, airconsole, unity-game-engine

Im working on building my own game for AirConsole. I am using Unity, have imported all relevant assets and have begun my project.

So basically what I want is two different sprites to show up on the users controller depending on if they have not touched the screen, or have swiped up on the screen and are holding. So far all my research has showed very basic controllers with just buttons. Is this even possible?

Comment: The controllers are pure html, so the only limit is your html, CSS and JS skills

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's absolutely possible.

The controllers are written in HTML. Javascript and CSS are supported. So anything you can do in a mobile browser can be done in an AirConsole controller.